# Return surface triangle of 3D scipy.spatial.Delaunay

Tags: python, scipy, cloud, points, delaunay

I have this problem. I try to triangulate points cloud by scipy.spatial.Delaunay. I used:

```
tri = Delaunay(points) # points: np.array() of 3d points 
indices = tri.simplices
vertices = points[indices]
```

But, this code return tetrahedron. How is it possible return triangle of surface only?

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

To get it to work as in code form, you have to parametrize the surface to 2D. For example in the case of ball (r,theta, psi), radius is constant (drop it out) and points are given by (theta,psi) which is 2D.

**Scipy Delaunay is N-dimensional triangulation, so if you give 3D points it returns 3D objects. Give it 2D points and it returns 2D objects.**

Below is a script that I used to create polyhedra for openSCAD. U and V are my parametrization (x and y) and these are the coordinates that I give to Delaunay. Note that now the "Delaunay triangulation properties" apply only in u,v coordinates (angles are maximized in uv -space not xyz -space, etc).

The example is a modified copy from http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html which originally uses *Triangulation* function (maps to Delaunay eventually?)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.tri as mtri
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay

# u, v are parameterisation variables
u = np.array([0,0,0.5,1,1]) 
v = np.array([0,1,0.5,0,1]) 

x = u
y = v
z = np.array([0,0,1,0,0])

# Triangulate parameter space to determine the triangles
#tri = mtri.Triangulation(u, v)
tri = Delaunay(np.array([u,v]).T)

print 'polyhedron(faces = ['
#for vert in tri.triangles:
for vert in tri.simplices:
    print '[%d,%d,%d],' % (vert[0],vert[1],vert[2]),
print '], points = ['
for i in range(x.shape[0]):
    print '[%f,%f,%f],' % (x[i], y[i], z[i]),
print ']);'


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='3d')

# The triangles in parameter space determine which x, y, z points are
# connected by an edge
#ax.plot_trisurf(x, y, z, triangles=tri.triangles, cmap=plt.cm.Spectral)
ax.plot_trisurf(x, y, z, triangles=tri.simplices, cmap=plt.cm.Spectral)


plt.show()
```

[image: Pyramid what the above example plots]

Below is the (slightly more structured) text output:

```
polyhedron(
    faces = [[2,1,0], [3,2,0], [4,2,3], [2,4,1], ], 

    points = [[0.000000,0.000000,0.000000], 
              [0.000000,1.000000,0.000000], 
              [0.500000,0.500000,1.000000], 
              [1.000000,0.000000,0.000000], 
              [1.000000,1.000000,0.000000], ]);
```

Comment: Great example. It does not generate a "closed surface" though - the bottom face (2 triangles) is missing. Is there a way to enclose it completely with triangles?

Comment: This question relates to how to create a  2D surface in 3D. This is a common problem (or feature) in creating meshes. There is no way you can map a 2D surface to 3D object without creating some sort of special point or points or lines. For example, think about how earths latitude and longitude are defined. They are perfectly 2d in equator and completely nuts in the poles. Latitude = 90 degrees defines the north pole and at north pole you can go from longitude 15 to longitude 67 or to longitude 87 smoothly and continuously. The point is that there is no standard way to do what you are asking.

Comment: I would split the problem in two (or more) parts and create two surfaces. Alternatively, it could be possible to create 3D triangulation and get the outer surfaces of the triangles. If you find a good way to do this, let me know. This is a very common practical problem.

Comment: My point could is a result from custom built 3d scanner. I realized that I have groups of points that have common z value that I could connect together. Then i can probably just triangulate between every pair of parallel lines

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you want to compute the [convex hull](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html) of your point cloud. I think this is what you want to do:

```
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull

hull = ConvexHull(points)
indices = hull.simplices
vertices = points[indices]
```

Comment: In this picture [link](https://mega.co.nz/#!udMUGBAJ!uCogbiSCoCY2dzR9KMzLjDOi-ntcdXgmTqYFFA6b0-E) you can see what point cloud I would like to triangulate. When I try to do convex hull, i'll get triangulation like in picture. I would like connect nearest points to triangle only

Comment: @s.t.e.a.l.t.h You won't be able to use the `scipy.spatial` functions to do what you're asking about, since it's based on [qhull](http://www.qhull.org/) which "does not support triangulation of non-convex surfaces...". You could perhaps break up your points into several convex surfaces.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I solved this problem by CGAL poisson reconstruction.

Answer (score 3):

Following Jaime's answer, but elaborating a bit more with an example:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d as a3
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from scipy import spatial as sp_spatial


def icosahedron():
    h = 0.5*(1+np.sqrt(5))
    p1 = np.array([[0, 1, h], [0, 1, -h], [0, -1, h], [0, -1, -h]])
    p2 = p1[:, [1, 2, 0]]
    p3 = p1[:, [2, 0, 1]]
    return np.vstack((p1, p2, p3))


def cube():
    points = np.array([
        [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1],
    ])
    return points


points = icosahedron()
# points = cube()

hull = sp_spatial.ConvexHull(points)
indices = hull.simplices
faces = points[indices]

print('area: ', hull.area)
print('volume: ', hull.volume)


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.dist = 30
ax.azim = -140
ax.set_xlim([0, 2])
ax.set_ylim([0, 2])
ax.set_zlim([0, 2])
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')

for f in faces:
    face = a3.art3d.Poly3DCollection([f])
    face.set_color(mpl.colors.rgb2hex(sp.rand(3)))
    face.set_edgecolor('k')
    face.set_alpha(0.5)
    ax.add_collection3d(face)

plt.show()
```

Which should depict the following figure:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't solve the OP's problem, as the surface could be rugged and thus using convex hull can leave some surface points untriangulated. Using alpha shapes could work as an alternative.